# How to change one window color of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, colors, window, themes, visual-studio-2019

I am working on three projects in three different visual studio 2019 windows (IDE). I feel difficulty to identify particular window among 3 windows for the same project/solution names.
since all windows are same theme/same color and two project having same name, same set of codes which makes me confusion to switch between those same color windows. I want to put individual color for each window like red, green, blue so that I will apply coding in appropriate window. How to apply different colors for each opened Visual studio 2019 windows(IDE). Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Customize Visual Studio Window Title](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle) extension to change the window title of Visual Studio to include a folder tree with a configurable min depth and max depth distance from the solution/project file, and the use of special tags to help with many other possible scenarios (Git, Mercurial, TFS...).